# Cast to generic type for protocol default method

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to make a protocol with a default implementation for a fetch request. The issue I'm having is that the type it should return needs to be generic and not something set from within the protocol but rather on what is calling it. Really what I just need is a method that you can pass in some type then use that for casting the value once you go to return it but from what I've read, this isn't possible in Swift since types are determined at compile.

This is the code I currently have:

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(type: T.Type) -> [Decodable]? {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName),
        result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)

    return result as? [type]
}
```

I'm getting the following error with the current code.

> Cannot find type 'type' in scope

Answer (score 0):

Just use `T` to cast your `results` array, like this:

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(type: T.Type) -> [T]? {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName),
        result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)

    return result as? [T]
}
```

or even better specify that `T` type is both `Decodable` and `NSFetchRequestResult`. Then you won't need type cast:

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable & NSFetchRequestResult>(type: T.Type) -> [T]? {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: entityName)
    return try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to conform the response to one of my custom `Decodable` types. When calling `fetchData()` on the sample you provided, I'm getting `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

Comment: @JoeScotto can you include the code that calls this function in your question?